# Noisy Scipy Wavfile Output Issue

Tags: python, audio, numpy, scipy, wav

I'm trying to create a .wav file using scipy.io.wavfile.write(), but the result is a noisy wav file, I have tryed with iNotebook with the same result, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

x= np.arange(25600.0)
sig= np.sin(2*np.pi*(1250.0/10000.0)*x) 

def makewav(data,outfile,samplerate):
    wavfile.write(outfile,samplerate,data)

makewav(sig,'foo.wav',44100)
```

It happens only when I try to generate pure tones. Any problem when reading the .wav whith scipy.io.wavfile.read() and writing again with scipy.io.wavfile.write().

Answer (score 3):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) you should output integer values, and you have floating point data so you should have to convert them first.

```
The method:
    scipy.io.wavfile.write(filename, rate, data)[source]

Argument:
    data is a ndarray A 1-D or 2-D numpy array of integer data-type.
```

To actually convert your data, try to use this code:

```
data=np.int16(sig/np.max(np.abs(sig)) * 32767)
```

[Check out more in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357992/how-to-generate-audio-from-a-numpy-array).

Comment: This works indeed! But why does using a float array produce a meaningful (frequency sounds ok) but noisy output?