# How to play sound from samples contained in NumPy array?

Tags: matlab, audio, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to find a function which corresponds to `soundsc()` and `sound()` in Matlab. Basically, I'd like to listen to sound by playing samples contained in NumPy array. Are there some functions for doing this?

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

This pertains to Linux & Mac

Most of Linux computers come pre-installed with `vox` library which let's you play audio from the command line.

So assume you write an array to wave file using `scipy.io.write`, you can play it from within Python program using the `subprocess` module.

Here's  a complete example:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import numpy as np


fs = 44100 # sampling frequency
input_array = np.random.rand(fs*2) # 2 seconds audio
write('output.wav', fs, input_array)

# now that file is written to the disk - play it
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["play", 'output.wav']) <-  for linux
subprocess.call(["afplay", 'output.wav']) <- for Mac
```

For Windows, as far as I know there are no built-in command line players - so you may need to install some program that lets you do so before using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether there exists a `numpy` function to do this, but you can convert your array (provided it only contains integers) to a wav file using [this function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) from `scipy.io.wavfile`, and then play the file.

I have not gotten into the details, but I think [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/) references useful tools for sound in Python.

Edit: see also [the answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357992/how-to-generate-audio-from-a-numpy-array)