# Normalize values between -1 and 1 inclusive

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I am trying to generate a .wav file in python using Numpy. I have voltages ranging between 0-5V and I need to normalize them between -1 and 1 to use them in a .wav file.

I have seen [this](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~barry/mydocs/MyCOMP28512/MS15_Notes/PyRefs/nbviewer.ipython.pdf) website which uses numpy to generate a wav file but the algorithm used to normalize is no long available.

Can anyone explain how I would go about generating these values in Python on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357992/how-to-generate-audio-from-a-numpy-array) may help.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/utility.py#L7) the thing you were saying is no longer available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1735025/1461850

Comment: Was the answer by @tom unclear? Do you still need help?

Answer (score 3):

isn't this just a simple calculation? Divide by half the maximum value and minus 1:

```
In [12]: data=np.linspace(0,5,21)

In [13]: data
Out[13]: 
array([ 0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ,  1.25,  1.5 ,  1.75,  2.  ,
        2.25,  2.5 ,  2.75,  3.  ,  3.25,  3.5 ,  3.75,  4.  ,  4.25,
        4.5 ,  4.75,  5.  ])

In [14]: data/2.5-1.
Out[14]: 
array([-1. , -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1,  0. ,
        0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ])
```

Comment: this is assuming that the minimum value is zero

Answer (score 1):

The following function should do what you want, irrespective of the range of the input data, i.e., it works also if you have negative values.

```
import numpy as np
def my_norm(a):
    ratio = 2/(np.max(a)-np.min(a)) 
    #as you want your data to be between -1 and 1, everything should be scaled to 2, 
    #if your desired min and max are other values, replace 2 with your_max - your_min
    shift = (np.max(a)+np.min(a))/2 
    #now you need to shift the center to the middle, this is not the average of the values.
    return (a - shift)*ratio

my_norm(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Asking bing gave me the right answer:

[image]

First you need to calculate the max and min of your peaks:

```
min = 1;
max = -1;
for (value in samples) 
  min = Math.min(min, value);
  max = Math.max(max, value);
```

Then loop the samples again and apply the formula to each value

```
for (i, value in samples)
  samples[i] = 2 * ((value - min) / (max - min)) - 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fit_transform method in [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). This method will remove the mean from your data and scale your array to unit variance (-1,1)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
data = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [2,1, 3]])
data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
```

And if you print out data, you will now have:

```
[[-1.22474487 -1.41421356 -1.06904497]
[ 0.          0.70710678 -0.26726124]
[ 1.22474487  0.70710678  1.33630621]]
```