# How can i pad wav file to specific length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav

I am using wave files for making deep learning model 
they are in different length , so i want to pad all of them 
to 16 sec length using python

Comment: Might check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757852/adding-silent-frame-to-wav-file-using-python

Comment: This could be done with `scipy.io.wavfile`, pydub, or pure Python (using the wav module -- though lower-level and a bit more tedious).  Do you care which tool is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub):

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

pad_ms = 1000  # milliseconds of silence needed
silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=pad_ms)
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav('you-wav-file.wav')

padded = audio + silence  # Adding silence after the audio
padded.export('padded-file.wav', format='wav')
```

`AudioSegment` objects are immutable

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, the question wants to fix all lengths to a given length. Therefore, the solution will be slightly different:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

pad_ms = 1000  # Add here the fix length you want (in milliseconds)
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav('you-wav-file.wav')
assert pad_ms > len(audio), "Audio was longer that 1 second. Path: " + str(full_path)
silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=pad_ms-len(audio)+1)


padded = audio + silence  # Adding silence after the audio
padded.export('padded-file.wav', format='wav')
```

This answer differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841521/5931672) in the sense that this one creates all audios from the same length where the other adds the same size of silence at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html). The L[ibrosa.util.fix_length](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.util.fix_length.html) function adds silent patch to audio file by appending **zeros** to the **end** the numpy array containing the audio data:

```
from librosa import load
from librosa.util import fix_length


file_path = 'dir/audio.wav'

sf = 44100 # sampling frequency of wav file
required_audio_size = 5 # audio of size 2 second needs to be padded to 5 seconds
audio, sf = load(file_path, sr=sf, mono=True) # mono=True converts stereo audio to mono
padded_audio = fix_length(audio, size=5*sf) # array size is required_audio_size*sampling frequency


print('Array length before padding', np.shape(audio))
print('Audio length before padding in seconds', (np.shape(audio)[0]/fs))
print('Array length after padding', np.shape(padded_audio))
print('Audio length after padding in seconds', (np.shape(padded_audio)[0]/fs))
```

Output:

```
Array length before padding (88200,)
Audio length before padding in seconds 2.0
Array length after padding (220500,)
Audio length after padding in seconds 5.0
```

Although after looking through a number of similar questions, it seems like `pydub.AudioSegment` is the go to solution.