# Why is my 2d array converted into list two list objects?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[0, 1, 7, 9], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]])
print(array1)
b = np.array([[10,20,34],[54,43,75]])
print(b)
arr = np.array([[0,1,7,9,12,18],[19,20,24,26,30]])
print(arr)
print(type(array1))
print(type(b))
print(type(arr))
```

Output - The first and third array give a different output even though they are created similarly

```
[list([0, 1, 7, 9]) list([1, 2, 2, 2, 3])]

[[10 20 34]
 [54 43 75]]

[list([0, 1, 7, 9, 12, 18]) list([19, 20, 24, 26, 30])]

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: When you do `np.array([[0, 1, 7, 9], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]])`, what do you think should be the *dimensions* (`.shape`) of that array? Keep in mind that Numpy arrays have to be rectangular.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are discrepancies between 2d arrays 1 and 3 vs. array 2. Notice the difference in list sizes. 2d arrays 1 and 3 are **not** rectangular, whereas array 2 is.
If you are seeing a `VisibleDeprecationWarning`, you can get rid of this error by adding `dtype=object` to the non-rectangular 2d arrays.
See provided comments below.

> [More on numpy arrays](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html)

> [More on VisibleDeprecationWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63102614/15489646)

```py
import numpy as np
# ARRAY 1
# 4 items, 5 items
array1 = np.array([[0, 1, 7, 9], [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
print(array1)

# ARRAY 2
# 3 items, 3 items
b = np.array([[10,20,34],[54,43,75]])
print(b)

# ARRAY 3
# 6 items, 5 items
arr = np.array([[0,1,7,9,12,18],[19,20,24,26,30]], dtype=object)
print(arr)
```