# How to transfer List of nested lists into a NumPy array?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following sample object:

```
list_sample = [['N', [], None], ['B:maj', [3, 6, 11], 11], ['C#:maj', [1, 5, 8], 1], ['Bb:min', [1, 5, 10], 10], ['Eb:min/b3', [3, 6, 6, 10], 6], ['B:maj', [3, 6, 11], 11], ['C#:maj', [1, 5, 8], 1], ['F#:maj', [1, 6, 10], 6], ['F#:maj', [1, 6, 10], 6], ['B:maj', [3, 6, 11], 11], ['C#:maj', [1, 5, 8], 1], ['Bb:min', [1, 5, 10], 10], ['Eb:min', [3, 6, 10], 3], ['B:maj', [3, 6, 11], 11]]
```

I would like to transfer this list into a ndarray, so I tried this method suggested in this post[Debugging Numpy VisibleDeprecationWarning (ndarray from ragged nested sequences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097829/debugging-numpy-visibledeprecationwarning-ndarray-from-ragged-nested-sequences):

```
np.array(formatted_chords,dtype = object)
```

But it gives me undesired result like this:

```
[['N' list([]) None]
 ['B:maj' list([3, 6, 11]) 11]
 ['C#:maj' list([1, 5, 8]) 1]
 ['Bb:min' list([1, 5, 10]) 10]
 ['Eb:min/b3' list([3, 6, 6, 10]) 6]
 ['B:maj' list([3, 6, 11]) 11]]
```

My target output would a ndarray which looks like this:

```
[['N',[],None]
 ['B:maj',[3, 6, 11]),11]
 ['C#:maj',[1, 5, 8]),1]
 ['Bb:min',[1, 5, 10]),10]
 ['Eb:min/b3',[3, 6, 6, 10],6]
 ['B:maj',[3, 6, 11],11]]
```

Can anybody shares how to do this transformation?

Comment: what is the reason you want it in an ndarray? Perhaps the solution best for you is not the answer to this question

Comment: You got what you want - an array containing strings and lists.  If you don't like that display style, stick with the list of lists.

Comment: When in an object dtype array, a list is displayed as `list([...])`.