# Ensuring Consistent Data Types in NumPy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Python script where I split each row of a 2D list, `my_list`, into two parts. The first part, `array1`, contains all elements except the last two of each row, and the second part, `array2`, contains the last two elements of each row. The challenge arises because rows in `my_list` can have varying lengths (Assume every row has more than 2 elements). Here's a sample code:

```py
import numpy as np

my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
back_crop = 2

list1 = [np.array(row[:-back_crop], dtype=np.float64) for row in my_list]
list2 = [np.array(row[-back_crop:], dtype=np.float64) for row in my_list]

array1 = np.array(list1, dtype=object)
array2 = np.array(list2, dtype=object)

print(array1, '\n', array2)
print(array1[0].dtype, array2[0].dtype)
```

This prints:

```py
[array([1., 2.]) array([5.])] 
 [[3.0 4.0]
 [6.0 7.0]]
float64 object
```

How can I modify this code to ensure that both `array1` and `array2` contains arrays with the `float64` data type, while maintaining the current array dimensions (without using padding with zeros or NA values)?

Comment: You can just eliminate `dtype=object` and it's going to "work" with a `VisibleDeprecationWarning`, which you could [suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097829). Maybe you can try to adapt this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45927484/15032126, but you are probably better just using a list of arrays.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, latest numpy versions give an error, not just the warning.

Comment: `array1` is shape (2,) with object dtype.  Elements are numeric dtype arrays with different lengths.  `array2` can be made without `object`, producing a numeric dtype and (2,2) shape.  With object dtype, it is still (2,2), but the elements are object.  `array1` is 'ragged' and there's nothing you can do about it. Generally object dtype arrays are no better than lists.  Don't use them if you don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lists and arrays:

```
In [57]: my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
    ...: back_crop = 2
    ...: 
    ...: list1 = [np.array(row[:-back_crop], dtype=np.float64) for row in my_list]
    ...: list2 = [np.array(row[-back_crop:], dtype=np.float64) for row in my_list]
    ...: 
    ...: array1 = np.array(list1, dtype=object)
    ...: array2 = np.array(list2, dtype=object)

In [58]: array1
Out[58]: array([array([1., 2.]), array([5.])], dtype=object)

In [59]: array2
Out[59]: 
array([[3.0, 4.0],
       [6.0, 7.0]], dtype=object)
```

`array2` can be made without `object`, getting a numeric dtype, still (2,2) shape:

```
In [60]: np.array(list2)
Out[60]: 
array([[3., 4.],
       [6., 7.]])
```

You can make a 'blank' array with shape (2,):

```
In [61]: array3 = np.empty(2, object)    
In [62]: array3
Out[62]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

and assign the elements of list1:

```
In [63]: array3[:]=list1; array3
Out[63]: array([array([1., 2.]), array([5.])], dtype=object)
```

or the elements of list2:

```
In [64]: array3[:]=list2; array3
Out[64]: array([array([3., 4.]), array([6., 7.])], dtype=object)
```