# Creating an empty AudioSegment File in Python (pydub)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydub, audiosegment

Beginner here. I'm trying to loop through a list of paths to mp3 files and merge all the mp3s:

```
combined_sounds = AudioSegment.from_mp3('./00.mp3')

for file in files:
  sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)
  combined_sounds= combined_sounds + sound;

# ....
```

I need to define `combined_sounds` before going through the list - but I'd like to not put anything into it before going through the loop. Right now my little hack is to use an empty mp3 file `00.mp3`, but this isn't the nicest solution. How would I accomplish this?

I tried `combined_sounds = ''` and `combined_sounds = None` but both get me errors when I then enter the loop and try to turn it into an AudioSegment. Can I create an empty AudioSegment before the loop maybe?

Comment: Do want to add some `silence` at the beginning?

Comment: No, I just want to merge all the files in the list. The `00.mp3` at the beginning isn't for silence, it's just because I didn't know how to declare the variable properly, so it's just a way around that :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `empty()` function in AudioSegment to create a blank segment:

```
combined_sounds = AudioSegment.empty()

for file in files:
   sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)
   combined_sounds += sound
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `final_song = one_sec_segment + song` in [Adding silent frame to wav file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757852/adding-silent-frame-to-wav-file-using-python), may be as above

```
#read wav file to an audio segment
song = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_in_file)
songggg = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_in_fileeee)

#Add above two audio segments    
final_song = songggg + song

#Either save modified audio
final_song.export(audio_out_file, format="wav")
```