# Generate an audio file from an array (spectrum...)

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is my first post.
I want to create a .wav file from an array of amplitude and frequencies.
How can I do this ? Thank you
I am able to get the spectrum too.

Comment: "Amplitude and frequencies": do you mean that what you have is a the result of an FFT transform ? Can you tell us how was this array generated ?

Comment: that's it, and i've made some transformations on my signal, so i have one array containing amplitude and one list containing frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [write function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) to create a wav file. Make sure that the array is in integers as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357992/how-to-generate-audio-from-a-numpy-array if you do not understand here is a link to someone's post who is more knowlegdeable then I.

Comment: Ok but what should my array contain ? The amplitude of the signal ?