# How to sound a signal in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I have a signal in Python, and I want to hear it. This is possible?.
The data is in the format `numpy.ndarray`.

In Matlab one can use the command `sound(data,f)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate audio from a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357992/how-to-generate-audio-from-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Combine that dupe target ("create a sound file") with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) ("play a sound file"). The latter has a numpy array-based answer down somewhere, perhaps that's better as a dupe target.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You can use scipy.io.wavfile library

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
noise = np.random.uniform(-1,1,100000)
write('noise.wav', len(noise), noise)
```

Comment: We cannot run your example because the variable `data` is not defined. Please consider testing before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module soundfile:

> import soundfile as sf
>
> sf.write(filename.wav, data, samplerate)

For further information read the [documentation](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/).